# fatal: Authentication failed for jenkins

Tags: java, git, jenkins

Good morning guys, I have a problem building my pipeline in jenkins, sometimes some jobs returning authentication error and sometimes they are working.

this is Jenkins version 2.164.2, git plugin version 3.11 and git client plugin is 2.8.0
Started by upstream project "PIPELINE_OI" build number 35
originally caused by:

```
Started by user Administrador Jenkins OI
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TRUNK/AUDITORIA J14/poi-auditoria-commons-j14
using credential dbebfd81-9cc5-4693-ad12-5b7f0e7dc845
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://innersource.accenture.com/scm/pmoi/auditoria-vj14_poi-auditoria-commons-j14.git
> git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TRUNK/AUDITORIA J14/poi-auditoria-commons-j14 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://innersource.accenture.com/scm/pmoi/auditoria-vj14_poi-auditoria-commons-j14.git
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
> git fetch --tags --progress https://innersource.accenture.com/scm/pmoi/auditoria-vj14_poi-auditoria-commons-j14.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://innersource.accenture.com/scm/pmoi/auditoria-vj14_poi-auditoria-
commons-j14.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:

stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://innersource.accenture.com/scm/pmoi/auditoria-vj14_poi-auditoria-commons-j14.git/'

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:655)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1152)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1192)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1816)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] done
Finished: FAILURE
```

sometimes passed, and sometimes returning this authentication error.

Comment: It's an HTTPS authentication error with Git - I would check to see if you have HTTPS credentials defined in your Git plugin and see if you have access to the Git repository using those credentials.

Comment: Alex, i undestand , but this error ocurred sometimes, i try again and this execution working, and tried after and error ocorred again.

Comment: What error(s) do you get when "it is failing"?  Authentication errors like this always mean that the user/password specified to Git are unauthorized to interact with the remote repository.

Comment: yes Alex, but the strange thing is to pass in some scenarios and in others the error happens, if it was an authentication error should always give this error, but solved the problem by switching to clone via ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changed the https call type with authentication to a public key via ssh

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to disable the credential helper that comes with the default Windows Git installation:

```
$ git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

In that case, Jenkins takes the control of Git authentication.

Reference [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/why-am-i-not-prompted-for-password-when-pushing-or-pulling-to-my-repositories-in-bitbucket-cloud-via-https-800293400.html#:~:text=The%20most%20likely%20reason%20for,c)%20for%20a%20specific%20repository.)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding SSH Public Key to Github. I use Jenkins in Docker so I exec into the container, generated ssh keys, added the public key to Github and added the Private keys to Jenkins credentials, voila! It worked.
I actually add this Authentication error when I was trying to 'Pipeline from SCM' [Add public SSH Key to your Github Profile](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)